# Symfony FOSUserBundle Group purpose

Tags: symfony, security, fosuserbundle, roles

I am trying to implement the [FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle) in my project.
I have just set up the [Group](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/groups.html) functionality, created a group and added a User to it.
What really confuses me is that the user doesn't inherit the group roles like I expected. My expectation was that If a user has a group that has the role `ROLE_ADMIN` for example, that the user also will have that role.
So something like

```
if (!$this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
        throw $this->createAccessDeniedException();
    }
```

would not throw the exception, but it does
To me that contradicts what the docs say here

> The roles of a group will be granted to all users belonging to it.

So my question is, how do I use Groups the right way?
Am I supposed to house all users in at least one group, and never check for the roles assigned to the user, but check their roles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The service `security.context` is deprecated along with the above change. Recommended
     to use instead:
     
     `@security.authorization_checker => isGranted()
     @security.token_storage         => getToken()
     @security.token_storage         => setToken()`

So just :

```
if($this->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN'))
```

Referre to Symfony Component:

```
protected function isGranted($attributes, $object = null)
    {
        if (!$this->container->has('security.authorization_checker')) {
            throw new \LogicException('The SecurityBundle is not registered in your application.');
        }

        return $this->container->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted($attributes, $object);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! I made a mistake while testing this. I didn't log out and back in, which caused the profiler to show that my user has no roles assigned. Well now it works perfectly